# Como criar um Splash Screen em Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, xaml

Como faço pra criar um Splash Screen em meu aplicativo?

Gostaria de exemplos!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veja esse artigo [Como criar uma tela de abertura para Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769511%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)(*Msdn - inglês*).

Tradução Livre:

> Se você estiver usando uma única imagem, você deve adicionar um arquivo de imagem que é `768×1280` nomeado `SplashScreenImage.jpg` para seu projeto. O telefone dimensiona automaticamente a imagem para o tamanho correto. Se você deseja fornecer telas iniciais de *pixel-perfect* para todas as resoluções, você pode adicionar as seguintes imagens para a pasta raiz do seu projeto de aplicativo.

```
WVGA 480×800   SplashScreenImage.screen-WVGA.jpg
WXGA 768×1,280 SplashScreenImage.screen-WXGA.jpg
720p 720x1,280 SplashScreenImage.screen-720p.jpg
```

> Cada novo projeto *Windows Phone OS 7.1* inclui um arquivo *SplashScreenImage.jpg*. Para personalizar a tela inicial, você pode substituir a sua própria imagem para a imagem padrão. Você pode substituir a imagem padrão com qualquer imagem que você escolher, mas deve ser de `480×800` pixels de tamanho, e ele deve ser nomeado *SplashScreenImage.jpg*. Você deve definir a propriedade [Build Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) da imagem para conteúdo.

### Exemplo

[**Aqui**](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Custom_splash_screen_with_progress_bar_for_Windows_Phone_applications)(*Nokia Developer*) há um exemplo que pode ser útil a você.

Primeiro crie um projeto com Modelo de Aplicativo do Windows Phone. Crie um *Windows Phone User Control* adicione um `ProgressBar`, `TextBlock` e um `Image`. A imagem é o splash padrão do projeto.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="480" Height="800">            
<ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,692,0,89" Name="progressBar1" Width="383"  />  
<Image Height="512" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Source="SplashScreenImage.jpg" />            
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="185,656,0,114" Name="textBlock1" Text="Please Wait..." Width="111" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" />        
</Grid>
```

No construtor *MainPage.xaml.cs* chamamos a função `ShowSplash()` para carregar o popup.

```
private void ShowSplash()
        {
            this.popup = new Popup();
            this.popup.Child = new SplashScreenControl();
            this.popup.IsOpen = true;
            StartLoadingData();
        }
```

Iremos inicializar a classe `Popup` e, em seguida, definir a classe `SplashScreenControl` para ser hospedado no popup. `IsOpen()` abre o *pop-up*.

Até agora o código irá carregar a tela inicial (pop-up) com a barra de progresso.

Agora vamos adicionar algum processo em segundo plano, e quando o processo em segundo plano fica concluída, vamos fechar o pop-up, como resultado, o usuário verá a tela inicial.
A função `StartLoadingData()` começa e completa o trabalho de fundo.

```
private void StartLoadingData()
        {
            backroungWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            backroungWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backroungWorker_DoWork);
            backroungWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backroungWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            backroungWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

Primeiro vamos inicializar a classe `BackgroundWorker`. Chamamos a função `RunWorkerAsync()` para iniciar a execução de uma operação de fundo e, portanto, `backroungWorker_DoWork()` é chamado.

```
void backroungWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //here we can load data
            Thread.Sleep(9000);
        }
```

Aqui vamos usar a função `Sleep()` para esperar por algum tempo. Quando `backroungWorker_DoWork()` expira, `backroungWorker_RunWorkerCompleted()` é chamado, que fecha o pop-up.

```
void backroungWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                this.popup.IsOpen = false;
            }
            );
        }
```

Assim, o usuário pode ver uma tela com a barra de progresso.